# Jumbled up ids in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

We have around 20 million records in our mongodb. In my collection called 'posts' there is a field called 'id' which was supposed to be unique but now it has gotten all messed up. We just want it to be unique and there are many many duplicates now.

We just wanted to do something like iterating over every reocrd and assigning it a unique id in a loop from 1 to 20million.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Did you not have a unique index on it? What about _id field?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - _id is untouched. i just created an index on the id field but that was after the ids were messed up. I am pretty new to mongo

Comment: What do you want to do with duplicate id values?

Comment: nothing really, just assign all the documents ids from 1 to 20million in a manner all stay unique. Data is supposed to be dummy data used for testing and comparing mysql and mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple script like this:

```
db.posts.dropIndex("*id index name here*"); // Drop Unique index

counter = 0;

page = 1;
slice = 1000;

total = db.posts.count();
conditions = {}; 

while (counter < total) {

    cursor = db.posts.find(conditions, {_id: true}).sort({_id: 1}).limit(slice);

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        row = cursor.next();
        db.posts.update({_id: row._id}, {$set: {id: ++counter}});
    }   

    conditions['_id'] = {$gt: row._id};
    print("Processed " + counter + " rows");
}   

print('Adding id index');
db.posts.ensureIndex({id: 1}, {unique: true, background: false});

print("done");
```

save it to assignids.js, and run as

```
$ mongo dbname assignids.js
```

the outer-while selects 1000 rows as a time, and prevents cursor timeouts; the inner while assigns each row a new incremental id.

Comment: i am running the script now ..it might take about 6 hours, but I have time. On the other hand the script wouldn't run the way you have said. Maybe we need to include a 'use db' command in your script. Anyway I just copied and pasted your script on the command line after I did a 'use db' command and its working now

Comment: did you forget the "dbname" arg? when you connect to mongo on the cli it will tell you the db it's connected to - by default it's test. 6 hours sounds really slow. Like an order of magnitude slow - patience :)

Comment: just for reference - I created locally 20M empty objects, and it took 23 minutes to run the above script on that collection.

Comment: I left mine running...took about 5 hours I guess. Buts its done. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There are not many options here, really.

1. Pick your language and driver of choice.
2. Fetch N documents.
3. Assign unique ids to them (several options here: 1) copy _id; 2) assign new ObjectID; 3) assign plain integer)
4. Save those documents.
5. Fetch next N documents. Go to step 3.

To fetch next N documents, you should note the last processed document's _id and do this:

```
db.collection.find({_id: {$gt: last_processed_id}}).sort({_id: 1}).limit(N);
```

Do **not** use skip here. It will be too slow.

And, of course, you can always truncate the collection, create unique index on `id` and populate it again.

Comment: how would i do fetch n documents in a loop? I dont have an id to fetch against. I think i would be using the _id? But then again how to I do limits?